# How do I parse an NSString of an array of JSON Objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I am having trouble parsing an NSString of JSON objects into different fields. The JSON objects is pulled from the table. The code to retrieve the JSON object looks like this:

```
NSString* retrievedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"{}"];
             NSArray *splitString = [retrievedStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];
```

The output of splitString:

```
"Array[",

  "\"image_link\":\"schedule_miss_vn\",\"start_time\":\"17:00\",\"end_time\":\"17:30\",\"viet_performer\":\"\\u0000N\\u0000h\\u0000?\\u0000m\\u0000 \\u0000L\\u0000e\\u0000g\\u0000e\\u0000n\\u0000d\\u0000a\\u0000r\\u0000y\",\"english_performer\":\"Legendary Group\",\"viet_event\":null,\"english_event\":\"Lion Dance\",\"day\":0,\"stage\":0",

    ",",

  "\"image_link\":\"schedule_miss_vn\",\"start_time\":\"17:30\",\"end_time\":\"18:00\",\"viet_performer\":\"\\u0000I\\u0000v\\u0000a\\u0000n\\u0000 \\u0000C\\u0000h\\u0000e\\u0000o\\u0000n\\u0000g\",\"english_performer\":\"Ivan Cheong\",\"viet_event\":\"Ca Nh?c\",\"english_event\":\"Singing\",\"day\":0,\"stage\":0",

    ",",

.....
```

It is basically an array of JSON objects.

What I would like to do retrieve and store the value of each field (i.e. value of start_time, end_time, etc.) for EACH JSON object in NSStrings so I can populate it in a UITableView, but I don't know how to parse the retrieved NSString to achieve what I want.

Can anyone provide some assistance?

Thanks

UPDATE:
The retrievedStr output looks like this:

```
Array[{"image_link":"schedule_miss_vn","start_time":"17:00","end_time":"17:30","viet_performer":"\u0000N\u0000h\u0000?\u0000m\u0000 \u0000L\u0000e\u0000g\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000a\u0000r\u0000y","english_performer":"Legendary Group","viet_event":null,"english_event":"Lion Dance","day":0,"stage":0},{"image_link":"schedule_miss_vn","start_time":"17:30","end_time":"18:00","viet_performer":"\u0000I\u0000v\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000C\u0000h\u0000e\u0000o\u0000n\u0000g","english_performer":"Ivan Cheong","viet_event":"Ca Nh?c","english_event":"Singing","day":0,"stage":0},
....
]
```

Comment: Why are you removing the {}?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just want to parse the NSString starting from { to } into an NSDictionary, for each json object, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you update me with the pure JSON string?

Comment: @Pangu: user  ' NSJsonSerialization' for parse son.

Answer (score 1):

insert a `{` in the head and `}` int the tail. And try

```
NSError *error = nil;
id appData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respose options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

Edit:
You're JSON is not proper.
Should be like this:

```
    { "Array" : [{"image_link":"schedule_miss_vn","start_time":"17:00","end_time":"17:30","viet_performer":"\u0000N\u0000h\u0000?\u0000m\u0000 \u0000L\u0000e\u0000g\u0000e\u0000n\u0000d\u0000a\u0000r\u0000y","english_performer":"Legendary Group","viet_event":null,"english_event":"Lion Dance","day":0,"stage":0},
{"image_link":"schedule_miss_vn","start_time":"17:30","end_time":"18:00","viet_performer":"\u0000I\u0000v\u0000a\u0000n\u0000 \u0000C\u0000h\u0000e\u0000o\u0000n\u0000g","english_performer":"Ivan Cheong","viet_event":"Ca Nh?c","english_event":"Singing","day":0,"stage":0}

    ]}
```

Comment: i'm not sure why it's not like that. Would it matter? Someone else wrote the database and I'm just retrieving the response from the database.

Comment: Yes, it matters. If the response is not in a valid format you won't be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [NSJsonSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) class

Comment: I have tried the code  NSDictionary *jsonReturn = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error] but the jsonReturn is returning null

Comment: @Pangu: Try to remove "Array" from the string, and you could use it with NSJSonSerialization. Else wise, your data is not a real JSON, so you will get null after trying a parsing.

Answer (score 0):

There are well defined opensource libs which can do this job for you.

One that I would recommend is: JSONModel
https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

Answer (score 0):

Have you try JSON Accelerator

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12

It will convert your JSON into Object

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood why your data was kept that way, but:
To get a valid JSON, you need to remove the "Array" from your String.
Then, you can use `NSJSONSerialization`.

So:

```
retrievedStr = [retrievedStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [@"Array" length])];
NSError *error;
NSArray *yourJSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON structure will not have the word 'Array'. Not sure how you get the data. If the returned data is already an Objective-C array (like what you present), your data structure is an array of JSON objects. You need to loop through the array and then decode the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

use `NSJSONSerialization` for parse json result.

```
NSError *error;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```